# NoSql alternative to Jakarta @Embeddable

Tags: java, jpa, nosql

I'm looking to find an alternative for Jakarta [@Embeddable](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/embeddable) to use with a non-relational database (MongoDB).

Embeddable allows to use composition over inheritance, but still have the fields on the same level.

Here a [simple example](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable):

Instead of writing all the fields on a class:

```
public class Company {

    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String address;

    private String phone;

    private String contactFirstName;

    private String contactLastName;

    private String contactPhone;

}
```

I can create a new class with common fields that I can reuse on many classes using composition:

```
@Embeddable
public class ContactPerson {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String phone;

}
```

So now I can use composition to compose a class with all the fields that it needs:

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String address;

    private String phone;

    @Embedded
    private ContactPerson contactPerson;

}
```

Comment: You can try referring the NoSQL mongodb java driver APIs.

Comment: Here is another one: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/nosql/1.0/ and its implementation at http://www.jnosql.org/

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: [@org.eclipse.jnosql.mapping.Embeddable](http://www.jnosql.org/docs/annotations.html#embeddable)

Comment: @prasad_ thanks for your answer, I'll check!

Comment: @prasad_ I would like to accept your response, so please share the link in the answer.